# CSRF Token Mismatch owasp zap

Tags: csrf, owasp, zap

After submitting the post request I am getting response code 419 with the error message "CSRF token mismatch". The application is using XSRF-Token cookie.

Please let me know how to solve this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`XSRF-Token` does not appear to be one of the default tokens ZAP recognizes. So you can simply add it via `Tools` > `Options` > `Anti-CSRF Tokens`.
https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/options/anticsrf/

The same can be done via the API as well: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#acsrfactionaddoptiontoken

Comment: Hi @kingthrorin, Thanks for your reply. I have already added the token to CSRF token list.  But still getting the same 419 error